# Trying to subtract the input of a UITextField by one but I keep getting an error

Tags: swift, countdowntimer

My code is here:

```
@IBAction func updateTime(){
        let inputVal: String = textMinutes.text!
        var inputInt = Int(inputVal)
        timerLabel?.text = "\(inputInt)"
        if  inputInt != 0 {
            inputInt -= 1
        }
        else {
            endTimer()
        }
```

So on the inputInt -=1 I keep getting the error "Cannot convert value of type 'Int?' to expected argument type 'inout Int'". I am not sure how to fix this or if my code is even correct here. This is all for this:

```
func startTimer() {

    countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

which is for the timer I am trying to make. I am pretty new to this so if there is anything else you need to see I can post it. I've looked all over for solutions but I have not found anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the point of trying to subtract 1 from `inputInt` since you make no use of the result? Why not directly assign `textMinutes.text` to `timerLabel?.text`?

Comment: Use optional binding in the if statement.

Comment: @rmaddy it is so the display on the screen will show the countdown

Comment: But the code you posted doesn't change anything. You set `timerLabel` to the same value as `textMinutes`. You don't do anything with the updated value of `inputInt`.

Comment: inputInt is an optional Int, not an Int (because conversion of inputVal could fail). You can't subtract 1 from an optional Int because it could be nil. I suggest you read up on the "guard" statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is bad. You don't want to change text of some label every second according to same other text every time.

---

You should create global variable for time, let's say `interval`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var interval = 0
    ...
}
```

then when you start timer, make sure that user wrote number and if does, start timer and set `interval`

```
func startTimer() {
    if let interval = Int(textMinutes.text!) {
        self.interval = interval
        timerLabel?.text = String(interval)
        countdownTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    } else {
        ... // handle case if user didn’t write integer
    }
}
```

then every time timer updates, just decrease `interval` and change `text` of your text field by this `interval` variable, then when `interval` is 0, invalidate your timer

```
@IBAction func updateTime() {
    interval -= 1
    timerLabel?.text = String(interval)
    if interval == 0 { endTimer() }
}
```